# Using UPDATE statement while using multiple WITH

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a sql statement that returns records that I need and I am using several WITH clauses. I am trying to update one column within the statement.

```
WITH <name_a> AS (SELECT...),
     <name_b> AS (SELECT...using 'name_a'),
     <name_c> AS (SELECT...using 'name_b')
SELECT * from <name_c>
```

How would I write the statement if I just want to update a column in the final <name_c> output? Ex.

```
UPDATE name_c SET fav_color = 'blue'
```

for all the records.

I tried just replacing the select with the update statement but I get 'Missing SELECT keyword'.

I found a similar question but it looks like this question focused on updating the value to what was returned from the select statement.  [Using "WITH" and "UPDATE" statements in the same SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688678/using-with-and-update-statements-in-the-same-sql-query)

Comment: What you show doesn't make sense. `name_c` is a subquery you create in the `with` clause; what do you mean by updating a subquery? `update` is usually pointed at tables (stored on disk), not at queries. Please clarify - what exactly are you trying to update? And, in any case, the `with` clause would come after `update`, not before it.

Comment: Trying to understand what you are trying to do... Do you mean that in the **output** you want column `fav_color` to have the value `'blue'`, instead of whatever comes from the rest of the code? That is trivial, and has nothing to do with `update`. You just can't use `select *`, you must name the columns explicitly, and give the hard-coded value to that one column. Like this: `select col1, col2, 'blue' as fav_color, price, col5, ... from <name_c>`

Comment: Ultimately, my goal is to update the value of `fav_color` of all the records that are returned from the final subquery.to `'blue'` in the table.   I'm not trying to change the output itself but the records in the table.  I found all the necessary values that needs to be updated by using the WITH clause.

Comment: Does your data have a primary key? It sounds like you want something like this: `update <table> set fav_color = 'blue' where pk_column in (with blah-blah-blah....  select pk_column from name_c)`. If your data doesn't have a PK column (or set of columns), you could use ROWID similarly, you would just have to SELECT it along with your stored data.

Comment: But, still, if you wanted to `update name_c`, that means that `name_c` is the name of the **table** you are trying to update. In the `with` clause, `name_c` is not the name of a table; it is the name of a subquery created by the `with` clause itself. This part still makes no sense. You still need to explain.

Comment: After using the with clause, you can `SELECT * from name_c` and return the output. `name_c` is the table of the subquery but it's taking the place of the table name in that statement.  I thought I could use a similar pattern for the UPDATE statement by replacing the table name with the subquery but it did not work.

Comment: I tried to use the primary key suggestion but I get an error saying "too many values".

Comment: Sorry - I gave up on this. I have no idea what you mean by updating something that looks like a query. Your latest explanation made just as little sense to me as the original one. I hope someone else will be able to understand what you are saying, and to help you. Good luck!